# Use viewport on Squarespace site

Tags: javascript, html, css, squarespace

On the page: https://heba-asmar.squarespace.com/ I am trying to set the homepage to 100% of the viewport.  That is, I want the entire homepage to fit within a browser window, no scrolling.  I have tried:

1) Adding height:100vh; to #thumbnail plus height:100% to the img.  This worked but left a blue bar at the bottom of the image---and meant that the image looked funny at certain screen sizes.
2) Playing around with adding these things to various other pars of the page, like #main and .desc-wrapper.

Nothing seems to work.  If someone could help me out with specifically what to target, that would be awesome.

Comment: Please add your code in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Are you trying to make your image responsive?  Why all the <p>&nbsp;</p> nodes?  Reducing the vertical padding on your <div class="banner-thumbnail-wrapper has-description"> seems to help too.

Comment: The p and nsbp nodes are just part of how SquareSpace centers the text in the image.  And yes, I am trying to make the image responsive.